# Connections shutdown error when using prepared statement

Tags: go, firebird, sqlx

I'm trying to solve a problem with a method in microservice that runs twice a day (7 p.m. and 7 a.m.). The microservice has 27 connections, all of them to Firebird, and when the error occurs I need to restart the method manually (it works fine on restart because the package that we use reconnects when the connection is not valid). The problem occurs time to time.

Please take a look at the code below. We use [SQLX](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx), **Firebird version 3.0**.

```golang
// The func is called inside a handler and len(stuff) is always > 1000.
func SetStuff(ctx context.Context, stuff []model.Stuff) (err error) {
    for _, v := range stuff {
        tx, err := db.BeginTxx(ctx, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        } 
        defer func() {
            errRollback := tx.Rollback()
            if err != nil {
                if errRollback != sql.ErrTxDone {
                    err = fmt.Errorf("unable to rollback transaction: %w", errRollback, err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
        _, err = tx.ExecContext(ctx, "SOME UPDATE", v)
        if err != nil {
            return 
        }
    
        err = tx.Commit()
        return
    }
    return
}
```

I've tried to reproduce the same error, but it wasn't successful.

**Error in logs**:

```
unable to rollback transaction: read tcp **********: read: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Make sure you updated Firebird server to the latest snapshot. There was a bug causing "connection shutdown" error on connection hammering has been investigated and probably fixed recently. You also can decrease connection rate using connection pooling.

Comment: @user13964273 Without further proof, I think it is more likely bug in nakagami/firebirdsql.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], and specify which Firebird version you're using.